# Can I integrate Sikuli and Selenium webdriver for flash and non flash elements

Tags: flash, selenium-webdriver, automation, sikuli

Need to automate a game-
First I need to automate home page like login/registration, and then need to automate game which is built on flash technology.
So I am want to automate non-flash elements using selenium webdriver and flash elements with Sikuli/SikuliX, is this possible to integrate both of them together in any possible way?

P.S: I can not use Selenium RC as it doesn't support flex.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that ... You need to download sikuli jar and add it with your selenium project

Refer below:-

http://nadimsaker.blogspot.in/2015/02/sikuli-how-to-install-and-run-sikuli-in.html

Note:- You need to handle all flash thing using sikuli only

You may face a Hkey issue while setting up sikuli:-

refer it for same:-

https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/235809

Hope it will help you :)